# How to chain and share prior results with Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I'm using the bluebird library and need to make a series of HTTP requests and need to some of the response data to the next HTTP request. I've built a function that handles my requests called `callhttp()`. This takes a url and the body of a POST.

I'm calling it like this:

```
var payload = '{"Username": "joe", "Password": "password"}';
var join = Promise.join;
join(
    callhttp("172.16.28.200", payload),
    callhttp("172.16.28.200", payload),
    callhttp("172.16.28.200", payload),
    function (first, second, third) {
    console.log([first, second, third]);
});
```

The first request gets an API key which needs to be passed to the second request and so on. How do get the response data from the first request?

UPDATE

This is the `callhttp` function:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var Request = Promise.promisify(require('request'));

function callhttp(host, body) {

    var options = {
        url: 'https://' + host + '/api/authorize',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: body,
        strictSSL: false
    };

    return Request(options).spread(function (response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
           // console.log(body)
            console.log(response.connection.getPeerCertificate().subject.CN)
            return {
                data: response.body
            };
        } else {
            // Just an example, 200 is not the only successful code
            throw new Error("HTTP Error: " + response.statusCode );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes that bits working ok and its returning a promise so the join is working OK.

Comment: I'm using the request library and have promisefied it.

Comment: Your three calls to `callhttp()` you show in your question are being processed in parallel so you can't use the results of any of them in the others.  Also does `callhttp()` return a promise?

Comment: can you add your `callhttp` function?

Comment: Just added the `callhttp` function

Answer (score 145, accepted):

**Edit in 2023.**  Now that we have `async/await` in every Javascript environment you execute in these days, the real answer to this is to use `async/await` as it vastly simplifies the collection and use of intermediate results into normal Javscript variables that can be used in any part of the sequence.  See the end of this answer for that conclusion.  The other parts of this answer were all written in 2015 before async/await was widely available.

There are a few models for dependent promises and passing data from one to the next.  Which one works best depends upon whether you only need the previous data in the next call or whether you need access to all prior data.  Here are several models:

### Feed Result of One to the Next

```
callhttp(url1, data1).then(function(result1) {
     // result1 is available here
     return callhttp(url2, data2);
}).then(function(result2) {
     // only result2 is available here
     return callhttp(url3, data3);
}).then(function(result3) {
     // all three are done now, final result is in result3
});
```

### Assign Intermediate Results to Higher Scope

```
var r1, r2, r3;
callhttp(url1, data1).then(function(result1) {
     r1 = result1;
     return callhttp(url2, data2);
}).then(function(result2) {
     r2 = result2;
     // can access r1 or r2
     return callhttp(url3, data3);
}).then(function(result3) {
     r3 = result3;
     // can access r1 or r2 or r3
});
```

### Accumulate Results in One Object

```
var results = {};
callhttp(url1, data1).then(function(result1) {
     results.result1 = result1;
     return callhttp(url2, data2);
}).then(function(result2) {
     results.result2 = result2;
     // can access results.result1 or results.result2
     return callhttp(url3, data3);
}).then(function(result3) {
     results.result3 = result3;
     // can access results.result1 or results.result2 or results.result3
});
```

### Nest, so all Previous Results Can Be Accessed

```
callhttp(url1, data1).then(function(result1) {
     // result1 is available here
     return callhttp(url2, data2).then(function(result2) {
         // result1 and result2 available here
         return callhttp(url3, data3).then(function(result3) {
             // result1, result2 and result3 available here
         });
     });
})
```

### Break the Chain into Independent Pieces, Collect Results

If some parts of the chain can proceed independently, rather than one after the other, then you can launch them separately and use `Promise.all()` to know when those multiple pieces are done and you then will have all the data from those independent pieces:

```
var p1 = callhttp(url1, data1);
var p2 = callhttp(url2, data2).then(function(result2) {
    return someAsync(result2);
}).then(function(result2a) {
    return someOtherAsync(result2a);
});
var p3 = callhttp(url3, data3).then(function(result3) {
    return someAsync(result3);
});
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(function(results) {
    // multiple results available in results array
    // that can be processed further here with
    // other promises
});
```

### Sequence with `await` in ES7

Since the promise chain is just a mechanism for sequencing asynchronous operations, in ES7, you can also use `await` and then the intermediate results are all available in the same scope (perhaps simpler than the separate scopes of the chained `.then()` handlers):

```
async function someFunction(...) {

    const r1 = await callhttp(url1, data1);

    // can use r1 here to formulate second http call
    const r2 = await callhttp(url2, data2);

    // can use r1 and r2 here to formulate third http call
    const r3 = await callhttp(url3, data3);

    // do some computation that has access to r1, r2 and r3
    return someResult;
}

someFunction(...).then(result => {
    // process final result here
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: The latter two solutions are also discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572)

Comment: Perfect code for fun and profit.

Comment: @TravisBear - `callhttp` can be any asynchronous operation that returns a promise that is resolved or rejected when the async operation is done.  There's an implementation of it in the original question here that this answer is based on, but it can be any async operation that returns a promise.

Comment: Added an option to use `await` in ES7.

Comment: very instructive post. ty

Comment: I find it surprising and slightly disturbing that most questions, posts and articles on the chaining of promises _do not_ in fact also discuss the passing of data through the chain; I thought I was missing something, when actually I was not. Thank you for the review, it is very useful. In my case I ended up using the "Accumulate results in one object" techinique, but the next time I'm going to try `async`/`await`.