# $q.all promises inject data from first promise to second promise

Tags: angularjs, promise

i would like to know if it's possible here with $q.all:

```
            var promise1 =   $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/"+id+"/users.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}

            })
            var promise2 = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+idname+"/tickets/requested.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}

            });

            $q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(data){
                console.log(data[0], data[1]);
            });
```

If it's possible to retrieve data from promise 1 and inject into the url of promise 2 and then retrieve full data of both promises in the same array ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, just `var promise2 = promise1.then(function(data) { return $http(…); })`?

Comment: yes exactly is that possible so ?

Comment: I've just shown you that it is!

Comment: But not with $q.all, which runs promises in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example like this

```
var responses = [];

$http({ ... }).then(function (response) {
    responses.push(response);
    return $http({ ... });
}).then(function (response) { 
    responses.push(response);

    console.log(responses[0], responses[1]);
});
```

See also [this answer, with many different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28714863/5520354) to handle it.