# How do you access content from a Promise that is in a then() function, accessing it in the next then() function

Tags: javascript, promise, resolve

How do you access content from a Promise that is in a then() function, accessing it in the next then() function.

My question is roughly explained through the following code.

```
someRandomPromiseFunction().then(function(theArray) {
  var newProm = _.map(theArray, function(arrayItem) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(arrayItem);
    });
  }
  Promise.all(newProm).then(function(theArray) {
    return theArray; // How do I access this in the next then() function
  }).catch(function(err) {
    return err;
  });
}).then(function(theArray) {
  console.log(theArray); // I need to access theArray from the Promise.all HERE
});
```

Comment: Might also be interested in [How to chain and share prior results with promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return the promise

```
return Promise.all(newProm)...
```

When you return a promise within a `then()` callback the outer promise waits until the inner one resolves/rejects. If the inner promise resolves, then that value is passed onto the next `then()` callback in the outer promise. Otherwise the reject value is passed to the next fail callback in the outer promise.

```js
new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   resolve("Main promise");
}).then(function(){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
       resolve();
   }).then(()=>"Stackoverflow");
}).then(function(data){
  console.log("Outer 'then()' data:",data);
});
```