# nested vs chained promises node js

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

I wonder what is better, nested or chained promises, or it depends on the context?
What are the cons and pros of each.

if I use chained promises, how do I reuse variable that were set in the previous promise?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain)

Comment: See [How to chain and share prior results with promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863)

Comment: okay but what is better?