# How to correctly express arbitrary Promise chains without "indentation pyramids"?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

There are methods such as `Q.reduce` and `Q.all` that help flattening a promise chain on the specific case of heterogeneous collections of promises. Mind, though, the generic case:

```
const F = (x) => x;
const a = F(1);
const b = F(2);
const c = F(a + b);
const d = F(a + c);
const e = F(b + c);
console.log(e);
```

That is, a sequence of assignments on which each term depends on arbitrary previously defined terms. Suppose that `F` is an asynchronous call:

```
const F = (x) => Q.delay(1000).return(x);
```

I can think in no way to express that pattern without generating an indentation pyramid:

```
F(100).then(a =>
  F(200).then(b =>
    F(a+b).then(c =>
      F(a+c).then(d =>
        F(b+c).then(e =>
          F(d+e).then(f =>
            console.log(f)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Note that using returned values wouldn't work:

```
F(100).then(a => F(200))
    .then(b => F(a+b))
    .then(c => F(a+c))
    .then(d => F(b+c))
    .then(e => F(d+e))
    .then(f => console.log(f));
```

Since, for example, `a` wouldn't be in scope on the second line. What is the proper way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Various methods here: [How to chain and share prior results with promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863).  In fact, this question may be a dup of that one.

Comment: @jfriend00: It's definitely a duplicate of the same one that one's a duplicate of, good find.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate, I see. I think this thread is turning out more instructive overall, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way that subsequent operations rely on multiple bits of previous operations, your choices are:

1. Do what you've done
2. Put the variables outside the chain and assign them as you go
3. Have the entire thing passing around an object with `a`, `b`, and such on it as properties

#1 is what I'd stick with, barring a *really* good reason to do either of the other two. Fortunately, that kind of accumulation rarely goes as deep as shown in your question.

---

`async`/`await` is the way to do it here some years later (and may have been when the question was posted, [the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) was finished and they could be used with a transpiler), see [Sterling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41682784/157247) for how they could simplify it. Here's a working example:

```js
const F = x => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(x);
        }, 100);
    });
};
(async () => {
    const a = await F(100);
    const b = await F(200);
    const c = await F(a+b);
    const d = await F(a+c);
    const e = await F(b+c);
    const f = await F(d+e);
    console.log(f);
})()
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

[Live on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAYjAvDAHkgfDA3gKBvmAJwFMoBXQsGMYgdxgAVCQBbASwmIAoSIQAbAG7EM2PAQmcoAFTYtiIMlC5cAlKNwStBXgOFcUqgNzjtAXwA0MAIwAGW8dMwzjsya4BDCAE8wwGGoaTqCQsB5IMB60HmywcFx2DiYSIdAwAEYRUTFxXABM9o4p4Gn-yNmx8J4A1OlFBKmwACZZ0ZXxHtXA9fiNMCLlbbnpXT0wfQBmrTlVTdXEY6kCxAB0_CAA5lwTrqpqOCvAHlDAABZcxITMhEESAPR3MCvPpx5gTfzEdyQADiCEsEu12eKxwLiMQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.7.7&externalPlugins=) for those with outdated environments.

Comment: async/await could help with scope, or you could use Promise.all() iirc to make chaining parameters easier. (I've used the async lib for node and it makes passing params easy)

Comment: @SterlingArcher: The `async`/`await` thing is a **very** good point (and if you're transpiling you can use it now).

Comment: Posted a much better answer haha, we can thank Luggage on the JS chat for that idea

Answer (score 3):

Second try. @Luggage in the JS chat suggested using Async/Await to keep the scope of your params.

```
let a = await F(200);
let b = await F(a + 100);
let c = await F(a + b);
//... etc, all inside an async function
```

You could also use `Promise.all` or (this is my experience) I've used the `async` lib to help waterfall these issues.

```
async.waterfall([
   (callback) => {
        let a = F(200);
        callback(null, a)
    }, (a, callback) => {
        let b = F(a+b);
        callback(null, b);
    }, //etc down the chain
]);
```

I think `Promise.all` would manage it better than an async lib, but async/await is the prettiest method here, though it will require ES2017 support/transpiling.

Answer (score 2):

Async/await solve this issue quite nicely I think;

```
async function runAsync(){
  const F = async (x) => x;
  const a = await F(1);
  const b = await F(2);
  const c = await F(a + b);
  const d = await F(a + c);
  const e = await F(b + c);
  console.log(e);
}

function runSync(){
  const F = (x) => x;
  const a = F(1);
  const b = F(2);
  const c = F(a + b);
  const d = F(a + c);
  const e = F(b + c);
  console.log(e);
}

runSync(); //5
runAsync(); //5
```

this will run natively with node 7 using `node --harmony-async-await example`

Unfortunately, you'll likely need to transpile down for general use and the output can get quite large.

Comment: there is nodejs async/await module which does it very good