# Passing Variables Through a Promise Chain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bluebird

Is there a better way to do this?

```
let foo;
return functionA().then(result => {
  foo = result;
  return functionB();
}).then(bar => {
  return functionC(foo, bar);
});
```

Notice that the result of `functionA` is required input to `functionC`. Using a  variable outside the promise scope works fine, but it feels kinda icky. Is there a clean idiomatic way to do this?

Please note that I do not have the opportunity to change the API of any of the functions I am calling.

Comment: you could try a nested promise :/ (also feels icky)

Comment: I think most of the options for doing this are covered in [How to chain and share prior results with Promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which you can pass an array of promises and it provides an array of responses within the `then()` callback when all promises passed in have resolved. You can access those array values to pass into `functionC`:

```
Promise.all([functionA, functionB]).then(values => functionC(values[0], values[1]));
```

Might be a little cleaner (without nesting) as it doesn't look like the response from `functionA` needs to be passed into `functionB`.

Otherwise, nesting would look like:

```
return functionA().then(foo => {
    return functionB().then(bar => {
        return functionC(foo, bar);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. ```Promise.all``` is best given my example. One slight simplification is ```functionC(...values)```.

Answer (score 6):

One option is, as [Alexander Staroselsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41903763/417562) writes, to use `Promise.all(functionA(), functionB())`. This runs the two functions simultaneously. If that's what you want to happen, you can use that answer. If, however, you want them to happen one after the other and then also be able to pass the result onto another handler, you can do this:

```js
function functionA() {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(1));
}

function functionB() {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(2));
}

function functionC(first, second) {
  return first + second;
}

functionA()
  .then(result => Promise.all([result, functionB()]))
  .then(function([first, second]) {
    return functionC(first, second);
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

The functions are obviously simplified -- but the lovely thing about Promises is that that doesn't matter: we don't care how complex they are or how long they take. Yay Promises!

The clever thing is that `Promise.all` doesn't mind if the values you pass are not Promises. If they are any other value, they are treated as a Promise that is resolved immediately. (In the same way that you can do `Promise.resolve(42).then(...)`.) So we can do `Promise.all([result, functionB()])`. This says "give me a Promise that is resolved when you have a final value for both `result` and `functionB()` and pass both values on". That is immediately in the case of `result` and at some unspecified time in the case of `functionB`.

The returned values are then passed as an array to the next `then` function.

```
.then(function([first, second]) {
  return functionC(first, second);
})
```

This then receives the values as an array (see the use of destructuring in the parameter list) and sends those values on to `functionC`. We then do one last `then` function to show the result.

Comment: This is useful when the result of the first `functionA` is used to call the second `functionB`, thank you so much!!