# How to pass variables through promise chain

Tags: javascript, variables, promise

I need to pass a variable through a promise `.then` chain. I can't find a way to work it out. I'm quite new to this so bear with me!

```
return foo.bar(baz)
         .then((firstResult) => {
           let message = firstResult;
         })
         .then(() => foo.bar(qux)
           .then((secondResult) => {
             message =+ secondResult;
             console.log(message);
           })
         )
```

What's the correct way of doing this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Variables Through a Promise Chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903625/passing-variables-through-a-promise-chain)

Comment: The 'let' variable has lost its scope in the promise chain.

Comment: Lots of different options illustrated here, depending upon the actual circumstances of your real code: [How to chain and share prior results with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863)

Comment: Do your operations have to go in this specific order?  Or could they be run in parallel?

Comment: @jfriend00 They can run in parallel, as long as the result can be used together. But I'd probably rather do them separately as they are calls into a database that I don't want to bog down. Thanks for your link.

Comment: This question is very comprehensively answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain why your code didn't work.

The scope of the 'let' variable remains between those brackets that you've put.
Thus, in the next `.then()` that message variable has lost its scope and you couldn't get it to work.

Read the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

To solve your issue you can declare the variable outside the promise chain and write it like so:

```
let message; // Declare it outside so that the variable is in scope throughout the promise chain

return foo
  .bar(baz)
  .then((firstResult) => {
    message = firstResult; // Set the value here
  })
  .then(() => foo
    .bar(qux)
    .then((secondResult) => {
      message += secondResult;
      console.log(message);
    }));
```

Refer to the following for a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/sivcan/h3pguw4e/

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. message is null.

Comment: @NathanLiu
Well, that was because I copied your code and didn't check it further below. My bad.      

`message = +secondResult` is wrong. 
      
It should be `message += secondResult` 
    
Here, check it out:  https://jsfiddle.net/sivcan/h3pguw4e/

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a promise chain for this.

You are making two, independent calls to `foo.bar()` and neither of them depend on the results of the other.

Make them independently, and get all their data at the end with Promise.all.

```
var promises = [
    foo.bar(baz),
    foo.bar(qux)
];
Promise.all(promises).then( results => {
    let message = results[0] + results[1];
    console.log(message);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be the best option.

Comment: @NathanLiu - This runs them in parallel which you said you prefer not to in your comment.  Jonas' answer runs them sequentially.  This probably gets the result a little faster and your database should be able to handle multiple requests just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just make one chain into the callback of the other:

```
 return foo.bar(baz).then((firstResult) => {
    let message = firstResult; 
    return foo.bar(qux).then((secondResult) => {
       message =+ secondResult;
       console.log(message);
       return message;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `foo.bar(qux)` only after `foo.bar(baz)` has completed.

This is how you call an asynchronous function inside another:

```
return foo.bar(baz).then((firstResult) => {
    let message = firstResult;
    // do some operation with firstResult
    foo.bar(qux).then((secondResult) => {
      message =+ secondResult;
      console.log(message);
    });
});
```

**Better approach**: You can create an array of `promise` then consume it using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) like this:

```
var promises = [
    foo.bar(baz),
    foo.bar(qux)
];

Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(error => null))).then( results => {
    let firstResult = results[0]
    let secondResult = results[1];
    console.log("firstResult -->", firstResult);
    console.log("secondResult -->", secondResult );
});
```