# jQuery attr() inside of Sweetalert2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

Currently I have a delete button on my datatable and I'm using `data-id` & class `btnDelete` just to get it the `id` foreach row.

```html
<button data-id="1" class="btnDelete">Delete</button>
```

Now I have this jQuery & SweetAlert code

```js
$(".btnDelete").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            alert(id);
        }
    });
});
```

But this gives me an error like this

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: id is not defined

BTW: I can alert the var `id` outside of the sweetalert but can't alert it inside the code of `sweetalert`

Comment: The code you've shown won't cause the error you've described. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: see if this helps :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912459/promises-pass-additional-parameters-to-then-chain

Comment: or this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464449/promises-how-to-pass-variable-into-then-function

Comment: because id is declared outside of [.then] function, so it is not accessible inside the function.