# Promise inside promise: what's the correct way to return a variable from the child promise? (JS)

Tags: javascript, promise

I've a function like this:

```
function top() {

  //promise1
  ParentPromise({
    ...some code here...
  }).then(function() {


    //promise2
        ChildPromise({
          ..some code here...
        }).then(function(response) {
         var result = response.result.items;

        });

});

};
```

and i need to return result value in this way:

```
var myresult = start();
```

How i can do that? THX

Comment: How is `start` related to `top`? Do you want `ParentPromise` to resolve to `result`?

Comment: it's a google api call. Does exist a way to get "return result"? I don't know, like a global variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to chain and share prior results with Promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The definition of promises is that you cannot literally assign `result` to `myresult`. *However*, you can make `myresult` a promise that resolves directly to `result` for the caller, however many promises were used to get that. The basic idea is that inside of each function in your above block, you should be `return`ing the next Promise in the chain. eg:

```
function top() {

  //promise1
  return ParentPromise({
    ...some code here...
  }).then(function() {


    //promise2
        return ChildPromise({
          ..some code here...
        }).then(function(response) {
         var result = response.result.items;
         return result;

        });

});

};
```

In the end, the code calling `top()` won't know or care that 1, 2, or 12 chained promises were used to get `result`. It will also be able to register an error callback in case any of those promises failed.

Comment: ok i understand, now i get [object Object] in console. How can i print correctly the result?

Comment: @ValerioMarzulli I'm not sure how to help since your example code didn't have a console.log(), so I don't know for certain how you're intending to retrieve/use the result. But, an example would be: `top().then(function(result) { console.log(result); }`. Before you ask, no, you cannot get `result` during the same function call - which is why we have promises and callbacks.

Answer (score 56):

The neatest way in my opinion is to return the promise and chain them 'down' instead of to the left, avoiding christmas tree-like callback hell.

```
function top() {
  //promise1
  return ParentPromise({
    ...some code here...
  }).then(function(parent) {
    //promise2
    return ChildPromise(parent.id)
  }).then(function(response) {
    // do something with `result`

    return response.result.items;
  });
}

top().then(function(items){
  // all done 
});
```

**Edit:**
Or in ES6 / lambda notation;

```
function top() {
  return ParentPromise().then(parent => {
    return ChildPromise(parent.id)
  }).then(response => {
    return response.result.items
  })
}

top().then(items => {
  // all done 
})
```

**Edit:** Or using Async/Await;

```
async function top() {
  const parent = await ParentPromise()
  const child = await ChildPromise(parent.id)

  return child.result.items
}

top().then(items => {
  // all done 
})
```

Comment: Yes, JavaScript Promises works that way. IMHO, yours is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following code, expanding to fit your specific circumstances.
Note how it illustrates returning Promises, adding logic at various points along the way, before, during and after handling various pending logic.

```
function ParentPromise(){
  // add complexity here, always returning a promise(s)
  // ie Promise.all, new Promise, Promise.reject or whatever...
  // here for simplicity, just return one to resolve with a clear value
  // to see it at the other end
  return Promise.resolve({items:1234});
}
function start() {
  // any method that returns the first promise, kicking off the complexity
  return ParentPromise(/*
    infinitely complex promise-conflation (individual or Promise.all, etc)
    only requirement is that each ***return a promise***
    where each is resolved or rejected
  */)
  .then((result) => {
    // do something with `result`
    console.log(result.items);
    // note returning what we want to come out **next**
    return result;
  });

};

var myresult;

start()
.then((result)=>{ myresult = result; })
.finally(()=>{ console.log('myresult:',myresult); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want

Let's say you have a model and some framework, you have something like this:

```
function promiseInsidePromise(req, res) {

    axios.get("example.com/api")

        .then(result => {

            // do something
            result = result + 1;

        })
        .then(result => {
            
            // call the other promise and return it into the chain
            return model.createOrder(result);

        })
        .catch(error => {

            handleError(error, req, res);

        });

}
```

You call the other prommise but return it's value into the main chain

```
 return model.createOrder();
```

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is that you're trying to use asynchronous code in a synchronous way.  You will need to change the way you think when working with asynchronous code.

One way to solve this is by having top() return ParentPromise, and then set the variable myresult using the .then() of the return of that promise.

```
function top() {
  ...
  return ParentPromie;
}
var myresult = ''; // default value until you have resolved your promise
top().then(result => myresult = result);
```

However, for this to work, you'll need to add code to resolve your promise:

```
var ParentPromise = new Promise(function(resolve) { 
  ... some code...
  var ChildPromise = new Promise(function(){
    ...some code...
  }).then(function(response){
    resolve(response.result.items);
  });
});
```

Comment: That means that the child promise won't resolve, hence its then won't even get called, hence the parent promise won't also get resolved, leading to the memory leak of 2 pending promises.

Comment: the most accepted way to write async code like it is synchronous is to use async ... await

Comment: This is wrong and misleading. `myresult` won't be defined as you try to access it, because the rest of the code doesn't wait for `top()` to resolve