# Can I resolve a Promise inside another resolved Promise?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm writing a method to iterate through a series of items to find either the next incomplete or the last one that returns a promise.

The item status is fetched by another method that also returns a promise and I'm trying to resolve/reject within the resolve callback of this method.

Simplified version of my attempt below:

```
export const findNextEntry = (i) => {
  let length = entries.length
  let entry = entries[i]
  entry.isLastEntry = i + 1 >= length

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getEntryStatus(i).then(() => {
      if (entry.status.complete) {
        if ((i + 1) < length) {
          findNextEntry(i + 1)
        } else {
          reject('no more entries')
        }
      } else {
        resolve('entry set')
      }
    })
  })
```

And then I call the method:

```
findNextEntry(entry.number).then((resolve) => {
   console.log(resolve)
}, (reject) => {
   console.log(reject)
})
```

The resolve/reject callbacks don't seem to be firing, and I get an error `Uncaught (in promise) no more entries`.

Comment: Might want to double check `store.dispatch('update' + `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Promise inside promise: what's the correct way to return a variable from the child promise? (JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895473/promise-inside-promise-whats-the-correct-way-to-return-a-variable-from-the-chi)

Comment: I bet the `getEntryStatus(i)` just throws (`no more entries`) and you don't handle this (you only attach `.then` to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probebly you must call reject/resolve for nested iterations

```
export const findNextEntry = (i) => {
  let length = entries.length
  let entry = entries[i]
  entry.isLastEntry = i + 1 >= length

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getEntryStatus(i).then(() => {
      if (entry.status.complete) {
        if ((i + 1) < length) {
          findNextEntry(i + 1).then(resolve).catch(reject)
        } else {
          reject('no more entries')
        }
      } else {
        resolve('entry set')
      }
    })
  })
```

Similar but more simple code

```
function test(i = 0) {
    console.log(i);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (i < 10) test(i + 1).then(resolve).catch(reject);
        else resolve('done');
    });
}


test();
```