# Is there a way to catch and return a firebase error from an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I would like to **catch and "retrieve" a firebase error**. However, the error is caught in an **arrow function**.

I have tried returning the error, but quickly realised it was being returning to the parent function and not to the variable it was being assigned to. I have tried a separate try and catch block but to no avail.

Here is the function in question to create a user in firebase authentication.

```
function signupEmailPassword(form){

    //variables
    email=form['email'].value;
    password=form['password'].value;
    confirmedPassword=form['confirmPassword'].value;

    //check if passwords are matching
    if(password==confirmedPassword){

        //creates a user with an email and password

        authentication.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred=>{
            form.reset();//reset form
            sendEmailVerification();//send a verification email

        }).catch( (error)=>{
            //errors messages
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = error.message;
            document.getElementById("message").style.color = "red";
        })
    }else{
        //passwords do not match error message

        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Passwords do not match";
        document.getElementById("message").style.color = "red";
    }
}
```

I would like to have access to the error variable that was caught in a separate javascript file. So I need to return the error when the function is called.

Comment: Quick observation, you could pass the error to another function inside catch, perhaps the function from the other file. You could conclude your catch block with something like `return targetFunction(error)`, and the targetFunction expects the error as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

An error-handler  can be passed as a callback function.

```
var errorHandler = (error) => { 
  ...
}

function signupEmailPassword(form, errorHandler) {
...
  }).catch( (error)=>{
     //errors messages
     document.getElementById("message").innerHTML =  error.message;
     document.getElementById("message").style.color = "red";
     errorHandler(error);
  })
}
```

Alternatively, Promises may be chained, such that each Promise returns a Promise. This is the way to approach the problem from a truly asynchronous perspective.

See [Promise inside promise: what's the correct way to return a variable from the child promise? (JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43895473/1164465)