# Better way to deal with Promise flow when functions need to access outer scope variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm creating a Node.js module to interact with my API, and I use the superagent module to do the requests. How it works:

```
module.exports = data => {
  return getUploadUrl()
    .then(uploadFiles)
    .then(initializeSwam)

  function getUploadUrl() {
    const request = superagent.get(....)
    return request
  }

  function uploadFiles(responseFromGetUploadUrl) {
    const request = superagent.post(responseFromGetUploadUrl.body.url)
    // attach files that are in data.files
    return request
  }

  function initializeSwam(responseFromUploadFilesRequest) {
    // Same thing here. I need access data and repsonseFromUploadFilesRequest.body
  }
}
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong like that, but I can't think in a better way to achieve the same result.

Comment: This will give you some ideas: [How to chain and share prior results with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863).

Answer (score 6):

Two simple ways:

1. write your function to take all parameters it needs

   ```
   const doStuff = data =>
     getUploadUrl()
     .then(uploadFiles)
     .then(initializeSwam)
   ```

   might become

   ```
   const doStuff = data =>
     getUploadUrl()
       .then(parseResponseUrl) // (response) => response.body.url
       .then(url => uploadFiles(data, url))
       .then(parseResponseUrl) // same function as above
       .then(url => initializeSwam(data, url))
   ```

That should work just fine (or fine-ish, depending on what hand-waving you're doing in those functions).

2. partially apply your functions

   ```
   const uploadFiles = (data) => (url) => {
     return doOtherStuff(url, data);
   };

   // same deal with the other
   const doStuff = data =>
     getUploadUrl()
       .then(parseResponseUrl)
       .then(uploadFiles(data)) // returns (url) => { ... }
       .then(parseResponseUrl)
       .then(initializeSwam(data));
   ```

A mix of all of these techniques (when and where sensible) should be more than sufficient to solve a lot of your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your code structured in the above snippet results in the `getUploadUrl()`, `uploadFiles()`, and `initializeSwam()` functions not being declared until the final `.then(initializeSwam)` call is made. What you have in this final `.then()` block is three function *declarations*, which simply register the functions in the namespace in which they are declared. A *declaration* doesn't *fire-off* a function.

I believe what you want is something like:

```
async function getUploadUrl() {             <-- notice the flow control for Promises
  const request = await superagent.get(....);
  return request;
}

async function uploadFiles(responseFromGetUploadUrl) {
  const request = await superagent.post(responseFromGetUploadUrl.body.url)
  // attach files that are in data.files
  return request;
}

async function initializeSwam(responseFromUploadFilesRequest) {
  // Same thing here. I need access data and 
  repsonseFromUploadFilesRequest.body
  const request = await ...;
}

module.exports = data => {
  return getUploadUrl(data)      <-- I'm guessing you wanted to pass this here
    .then(uploadFiles)
    .then(initializeSwam);
}
```

This approach uses ES6 (or ES2015)'s `async/await` feature; you can alternatively achieve the same flow control using the [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) Promise library's *coroutines* paired with [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).