# Promises and async/await in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, async-await

My sample code:

```
let name;

 Login.findOne().then(() => {
   name = 'sameer';
 }); // consider this is async code

console.log(name);
```

So the above code works async, so now my console.log became undefined.

I used callbacks to make the code work like synchronous.

My callback code:

```
let name;

 const callback = () => {
  console.log(name);
 };

 Login.findOne().then(() => {
   name = 'sameer';
   callback();
 });
```

Now its working perfectly,

My question is how you replace this small code with promises and async await instead of callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` lets you write asynchronous code in a somewhat synchronous fashion:

```
async function doIt() {
    let name = await Login.findOne();
    console.log(name);
    // You can use the result here
    // Or, if you return it, then it becomes the resolved value
    // of the promise that this async tagged function returns
    return name;
}

// so you can use `.then()` to get that resolved value here
doIt().then(name => {
    // result here
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

The plain promises version would be this:

```
function doIt() {
    // make the query, return the promise
    return Login.findOne();
}

// so you can use `.then()` to get that resolved value here
doIt().then(name => {
    // result here
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

Keep in mind that `await` can only be used inside an `async` function so sooner or later, you often still have to use `.then()` to see when everything is done.  But, many times, using `await` can simplify sequential asynchronous operations.

It makes a lot more difference if you have multiple, sequential asynchronous operations:

```
async function doIt() {
    let result1 = await someFunc1();
    let result2 = await someFunc2(result1 + 10);
    return someFunc3(result2 * 100);
}
```

Without await, this would be:

```
function doIt() {
    return someFunc1().then(result1 => {
        return someFunc2(result1 + 10);
    }).then(result2 => {
        return someFunc3(result2 * 100);
    });
}
```

Add in more logic for processing the intermediate results or branching of the logic flow and it gets more and more complicated without `await`.

For more examples, see [How to chain and share prior results with Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863) and how much simpler the `await` version is.

Comment: where is the await keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Though you can use anonymous functions, I am just going to declare a function called printName like so, for clarity.

```
function printName(name) {
    // if name provided in param, then print the name, otherwise print sameer.
    console.log(name || 'sameer')
}
```

With promise, you can do:

```
Login.findOne().then(printName).catch(console.error)
```

With async/await. It has to be in a function declared async.

```
async function doLogin() {
     try {
       const name = await Login.findOne()
       printName(name)
     } catch(e) {
       console.error(e)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your current approach is already promise based, you can add the console.log directly under `name = 'sameer';` and get the result you're looking for.
See here for an overview of promises prototype - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

```
Login.findOne().then(() => {
   name = 'sameer';
   console.log(name);
 });
```

If you wanted to use async/await, you'd need to wrap this logic in a async function, but you could then use it like this:

```
async function someFunction() { 
    const resultFromFindOne = await Login.findOne();
    name = 'sameer';
    console.log(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how you replace this small code with promises and async await instead of callbacks

Here you go, 2 ways to do it:

```js
/* Let's define a stand-in for your Login object so we can use Stack Snippets */
const Login = {
  findOne: (name) => Promise.resolve(name) // dummy function
  }


/* using promises */
Login.findOne('sameer')
  .then(name => name.toUpperCase())  // the thing you return will be passed to the next 'then'. Let's uppercase just for fun
  .then(name => console.log('**FROM PROMISE**', name))


/* using async/await */
async function main() {                      // (A) only inside async can you use await
  const name = await Login.findOne('sameer') // as mentioned in (A)
  console.log('**FROM AWAIT**', name)
}
main() // trigger our async/await test
```

Cheers,