# How to keep response url and response body through .then() chain?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I am trying to keep my response url and the response body for further processing.
if I return res.json() like I normally do, then I lose the res.url value.

But if I add code to get the res.url, then I'm having trouble getting my res.json() promise to resolve.

My last attempt was to try to make an async/await function for the res.json() but that isn't working for me either:

```
 fetch(url, options).then((res)=>{
    let obj = getJSON(res);
    let profileUrn = res.url.match(/(?<=urn%3Ali%3Afsd_profile%3A).+(?=&)/)[0];
    let rep = {
        profileUrn,
        obj
    };
    return rep;
}
).then((data)=>{
    console.log(data.profileUrn);
    console.log(data.obj);
}
);

async function getJSON(res){
        let data = await res.json();
        return data;    
    };
```

Comment: Here's a list of your various options: [How to chain and share prior results with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just making the first `then()` callback `async` then you can *await* `res.json()`

```
fetch(url, options).then(async (res)=>{
                       // ^^^ async 
    let obj = await res.json();
           //  ^^ await the json promise
    let profileUrn = res.url.match(/(?<=urn%3Ali%3Afsd_profile%3A).+(?=&)/)[0];
    let rep = {
        profileUrn,
        obj
    };
    return rep;
}).then((data)=>{
    console.log(data.profileUrn);
    console.log(data.obj);
});
```

Note you need to add additional error handling yourself

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this without `async/await` keywords, you may use `Promise.all` to return an array of promises and non-promises:

```
fetch(url, options)
  .then(res => Promise.all([res.url, res.json()]))
  .then(([url, obj]) => {
    console.log(url);
    console.log(obj);
  });
```

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that fulfills when the iterable contains promises that have been fulfilled and non-promises that have been returned. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

or, chain the `json()` promise while `res` is still in the same scope:

```
fetch(url, options)
  .then(res => res.json().then(obj => [res.url, obj])) 
  .then(([url, obj]) => {
    console.log(url);
    console.log(obj);
  });
```

If you want to achieve this with `async/await` keywords:

```
// These must be used inside an async function.

const res = await fetch(url, options)
const obj = await res.json();
const url = res.url;
```

There are probably more ways to do it (including @charlietfl's answer). Try to understand them and pick one that suits your style. JavaScript is fun!

Comment: clever use of Promise.all()

Comment: Thanks, this question made me read the MDN Docs of `Promise.all`. Learning by teaching is good.