# How can I avoid promise chain drilling?

Tags: javascript, promise

My promise chain looks like this:

```
PromiseA()
.then((A) => PromiseB(A))
.then((B) => PromiseC(B))
...
.then((X) => PromiseY(X))
.then((Y) => PromiseZ(Y, A))
```

How do I use parameter A in the last promise without drilling through all the promises like so:

```
PromiseA()
.then((A) => Promise.all[A, PromiseB(A)])
.then(([A, B]) => Promise.all[A, PromiseC(B)])
...
.then(([A, X]) => Promise.all[A, PromiseY(X)])
.then(([A, Y]) => PromiseZ(A, Y))
```

Comment: `async/await` is generally the easiest way to avoid messes like this.

Comment: By avoiding promise chains.

Comment: I agree `async/await` is the way to go, but all the ways you can share prior results into later spots in the promise chain are discussed here: [How to chain and share prior results with Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refactor your function to `async`/`await`:

```
async function fun() {
  const A = await PromiseA();
  const B = await PromiseB(A);
  const C = await PromiseC(B);
  // ...
  const Y = await PromiseY(A, B, C);
  const Z = await PromiseZ(Y, A);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the chain inside the first `.then()` callback so that `A` is still in scope.

```
PromiseA()
.then((A) => 
    PromiseB(A)
    .then(PromiseC)
    .then(PromiseD)
    .then(PromiseE)
    ...
    .then((Y) => PromiseZ(Y, A)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a variable to store it.

```
let a;
PromiseA()
.then(A => (a = A, PromiseB(A))
.then(B => PromiseC(B))
...
.then(X => PromiseY(X))
.then(Y) => PromiseZ(a, Y));
```